# incorrect display of characters in price block of prestashop

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I hope this picture show you, what is the problem.

Problem appears only in chrome-based browser's.

I use russia currency as default. Upload price in dollar.

Symbols similar to hieroglyphics, Thai or Japanese.

[Picture that show the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeBkD.jpg)

I ask you to share the reasons why this is so.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: What's the encoding of your database?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that problems the correct settings for the database is:

Encoding: `uft8`
Collation: `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Already have. And problem appears only in price block, not in a description or product name.

I created database with  "... DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;" command

Comment: Do you have a public link that we can see?